# Computed column

Tags: sql-server-2005

In current table I have a column that holds the date field in ddmmyyyy format and it is of type varchar(8). The column has some string value also. I want to create a computed column that will hold the value in DateTime format if the value in source column is valid date time.

Comment: Friendly advice: All the answers below fail to address the DateFormat problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your varchar(8) column is `dateString` :

```
Cast([dateString] as datetime)
```

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. Try 
Select  Cast('01011900' as datetime) as myDate.
The following will work 
Select  Cast('19000101' as datetime) as myDate.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do a TRY CATCH inside a computed column expression. You will have to do some data cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

try parsing your varchar into dd/mm/yyyy before attempting the cast:

```
cast(substring([datestring],1,2) + '/' + 
substring([datestring],3,2) + '/' + 
substring([datestring],5,4) as datetime)
```

Comment: This question has a SQL2005 tag.  The DATE data type was added in SQL2008.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server prefers dates in the format of yyyymmdd so there will be some string manipulation involved to format your data like this.  We should also use the IsDate function to make sure we have a valid date.

So:

```
Cast(Case When IsDate(Right(@Data, 4) 
     + SubString(@Data, 3, 2) 
     + Left(@Data, 2)) = 1 
        Then Right(@Data, 4) 
           + SubString(@Data, 3, 2) 
           + Left(@Data, 2) End  As DateTime)
```

Notice that this code should correctly handle invalid dates contained within your varchar column.  If a date is invalid, this code will return NULL.